# Buy 25 pieces of jelly of 3 flavours with at least 5 of 1 flavour. How many ways to buy the flavours?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, characteristic-functions, piecewise-continuity

> Terra, Ventus and Aqua are very good friends, almost like siblings. To celebrate Terra’s job promotion, Ventus and Aqua decided to buy Terra’s favorite dessert, fruit-flavored jelly, particularly cherry-flavored jelly. The two decided to buy a total of 25 pieces of jelly of varying flavors:
>
> - cherry,
> - blueberry and
> - kiwi.
>
> When they arrived at the jelly market, they find that there are only 9 pieces of jelly left for each of the three flavors that they want to buy.
>
> Since it’s also Terra’s birthday, they would buy at least 5 pieces of cherry-flavored jelly.
>
> Now, in how many ways can they pick the flavors for the remaining pieces of jelly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_i, i = 1,2,3$ be the number of pieces of jelly from cherry, blueberry and kiwi respectively.  They have decided that they buy 5 pieces of cherry for the birthday girl.  They also decided that they will buy 25 of which 5 is cherry and the rest  20 from the remanining flavors including cherry.  There are only 9 available in each flavor for 2 and 3 and only 4 available for 1 ( as she would scoop 5 already).

$x_i \le 9, i = 2,3$ and $x_1\le4$

Let $y_i = 9-x_i, i = 2,3$ and $y_1 = 4-x_1$ with $y_i's\ge0$

The classic problem is $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 20$

or $4-y_1+9-y_2+9-y_3 = 20$

or $y_1+y_2+y_3 = 2$

The number of solutions for this would be the number of ways they could buy the 20 jellies which is ${(2+3-1)\choose(3-1)} = 6$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $7+9+9$ and $8+8+9$ are the only ways to partition $25$ into three unlabelled heaps such that no heap is more than $9$.

So how many ways are there to select heaps of cherry, blueberry, and kiwi flavours such that no heap is more than $9$?

Answer (score 1):

At the jelly store, they would have already taken 5 cherry flavored jellies for Tara. This leaves 4 cherry, 9 blue berry and 9 kiwi left. They still have to choose 20 more to get to 25.

If we take $c$ to be the number of cherry flavored jellies, $b$ the number of blue berry flavored jellies and $k$ to be the number of kiwi flavored jellies they choose, we have:

$$ c+b+k = 20 $$

but they can't just choose any number like 18 kiwi since the store has a limited stock.

Our constraints are:

$$ c≤4  $$

$$ b≤9  $$

$$ k≤9  $$

If we call new variables as $C$, $B$ and $W$ where $C = 4-c$, $B =9-b$ and $K = 9-k$, (as these new variables will always be non-negative) our equation will now be:

$$C +B + K = 2$$

That has the solutions $(C,B,K)$ = $(2,0,0)$,$(0,2,0)$,$(0,0,2)$,$(0,1,1)$,$(1,0,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$.

So, 6 ways.

Answer (score 0):

i might be misinterpreting but

- case 1: 5 cherry.

under case 1 you could have

0 blueberry 20 kiwi, 1 b 19 k, ..., 19 k 1 b, 20k 0b

for a subtotal of 21 subcases.

- for case 2: 6 cherry

you have

0 blueberry 19 kiwi, 1b 18 k, ..., 19 b 0 k

for a subtotal of 20 cases.

- case 3 has 19 subcases.
- case 4: 18
- case 5: 17

soooo $21+20+19+18+17=95$

?

Or use piecewise/indicator/characteristic functions to say 21, 20, 19, 18 or 17 depending on how many cherry pieces bought.

Comment: There are 9 pieces available for each of the three flavours.  So it is impossible to buy 20 pieces of kiwi, etc.

Comment: @GrahamKemp lol thanks

Comment: Why didn't you include this attempt as part of your question?